# which scheme better for a playlist relationship table? Auto increment key or unique key?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, performance

I created a table for my WP plugin, it stored the relationships of playlists and items.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$wpdb->playlist_relationships` (
                `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                `item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
                `list_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
                `item_order` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
                `time_added` datetime NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY  (id),
                KEY list_id (list_id),
                KEY item_id (item_id)
            );";
```

But there is a scenario that makes me think about which index schema I should use: Update item order.

If use the schema above, then update item orders will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->table} (id, item_order) VALUES (31, 1),(32, 2)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_order=VALUES(item_order);
```

Since list_id+item_id is always unique, so I consider whether it can be changed to the following scheme:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$wpdb->playlist_relationships` (
                `item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
                `list_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
                `item_order` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
                `time_added` datetime NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (list_id, item_id),
                KEY list_id (list_id),
                KEY item_id (item_id)
            );";
```

then update orders will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->table} (list_id, item_id, item_order) VALUES (1024, 31, 1),(1024, 32, 2)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE list_id=VALUES(list_id), item_id=VALUES(item_id), item_order=VALUES(item_order);
```

The advantage of this schema is we don't need to use auto increment ID in front-end logic since the list_id and item_id must be known.

But I'm not very familiar with database performance, not sure which one is more suitable or even have better solution? after googled someone said Increment-ID have faster speed for data writing than primary-unique-key method.

My English is not very good, I hope I have described the problem clearly enough. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a 1-to-many relationship (each item is in only 1 list)?  Or many-to-many (an item can be in many lists)?

Comment: many to many, just like youtube playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each "item" can be in only one "list", then neither is optimal.  Instead, put `list_id,` time_added`, and` item_order`in the`Items` table.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

If this is many-to-many, then Option 2 is better. Some  further improvements:

```
            PRIMARY KEY (list_id, item_id),  -- good
            KEY list_id (list_id),           -- redundant; toss
            KEY item_id (item_id)  -- change to (item_id, list_id)
```

And the IODKU can be shortened by removing the updating of the PK columns:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->table} (list_id, item_id, item_order)
    VALUES (1024, 31, 1),(1024, 32, 2)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        item_order = VALUES(item_order);
```